# How can I resolve my authorisation error with Joomla and the JCE editor?

Tags: joomla1.5

I use a front-end login for editing my website; And as an editor I use JCE editor which works great.

For inserting images I usually use this option, and it works very well.

[image: Option]

But recently when I click this icon I see this error:

> You are not authorised to view this resource.

How can I resolve this issue?